# How can I write a streaming tar file from a generator?

Tags: python, stream, generator, parquet, tar

I have a generator that returns a parquet file, I would like to add this parquet in streaming piece by piece to a tar file every time the generator returns a part of the parquet file

I expect something like this:

```
def tar_generator(parquet_generator, log_generator):
    """Streams a tar file containing the parquet file"""
    tar_stream = BytesIO()
    tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=tar_stream, mode="w")

    # Add Parquet file to the TAR
    parquet_stream = parquet_generator()
    tarinfo = tarfile.TarInfo(name="name.parquet")
    tar.addfile(tarinfo)
    fileobj = tar.fileobj
    fileobj.write(parquet_stream)

    tar_stream.seek(0)
    yield tar_stream.read()
```